# How to locate a textfield in Flash Pro CS6?

Tags: flash-cs6

I'm updating a large .fla file from AS2.0 to AS3.0 and get the following warning:

> WARNING: Text field variable names are not supported in ActionScript
>   3.0. The variable '_text' used for the text field '_textField' will not be exported. Fonts should be embedded for any text that may be
>   edited at runtime, other than text with the "Use Device Fonts"
>   setting. Use the Text > Font Embedding command to embed fonts.

Is there a **quick** way to locate the offending symbol? The Flash Pro "Find" function does not seem to be helpful for this (or anything else for that matter, at least on my Windows 7 computer).

Thank you.

Comment: The Movie Explorer panel will list a text field's variable name in parentheses after the text inside the field. E.g., Here's some text inside my field, (myTextVariable), <instanceName>, (TimesNewRoman, 12 pts)

Comment: I tried that but didn't see any text fields displayed. That's probably because I'm not adding anything to the stage inside .fla. Everything is done in AS3. So, I added all symbols to stage to try if search would work and it did! Thank you!

Comment: In the Movie Explorer's Settings dialog, just click "Symbol definitions" to include text fields that aren't on the stage.

Comment: One would think that checking "Symbol definitions" should work, but in reality it doesn't, at least on my computer. Temporarily adding all symbols to stage is good enough. Would you like to post your answer so that I could mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Movie Explorer panel will list a text field's variable name in parentheses after the text inside the field. E.g.:

Here's some text inside my field, (myTextVariable) , (TimesNewRoman, 12 pts)

Comment: Temporarily add all symbols to stage to make sure the Movie Explorer sees them.